# SSL certificate works fine on my loclhost (xampp), but doesnt work with localhost:9001

Tags: php, ssl, phpmyadmin, xampp, ssl-certificate

i made a ssl cert and key and i am using it on my localhost (xampp). But if i access localhost:9001 it shows the certificate is invalid.

[image: localhost image]

[image: localhost 9001 image]

Answer (score 0):

Port 9001 is another service. So you have to put the certificate in that service, too. Otherwise you get that error. Normally XAMPP is running under 80 and 443.

Comment: I used the following method to apply SSL on localhost. https://blog.kylehuynh.com/enable-ssl-in-apache-of-xampp-mac-osx/

Can you help me with how to include :9001 ?  @René Höhle